# Importing of Test Library (python) in robotframeworks

Tags: robotframework

I've created a test library for robotframework named MyLibrary.py and it contains the ff code:

```
class Mylibrary(object):

def concat_string(self,str1,str2):
    return str1 + " " + str2
```

I saved it in the folder of my pythonpath

For my resource file, I put
[common.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fdIo.jpg)
to import my test library
I have separate file for my keyword and test case. 
[keyword.txt & myscript.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBoxH.gif)

When running my test case using pybot, I always encountered "No keyword with the name found "Concat String" found.

What seems to be the problem? I really can't solve it.

Comment: Can you share ***Settings *** section of your myscript.txt file?, it looks like a mapping issue.

Comment: excatly, i am pretty sure its a mapping issue! :)

Comment: please don't include links to images of code. Take the time to properly add the code to the question.